# Regex capture TLD from Palo Alto URL Filtering logs

Tags: regex

I am attempting to capture the TLD out of a URI generated in Palo Alto threat logs. The TLD could be anything but is always found in the syslog between the following common syntax:

```
beginning: **Miscellaneous="**  
end: **/"**

Examples:  
Miscellaneous="example1.com/"  
Miscellaneous="example2.gov.au/"  
Miscellaneous="example3.co.uk/"
```

Asking for help with the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the language you are using, you can use lookarounds to assert that a period precedes some text and a forward slash follows.

```
/(?<=\.)[a-z0-9]+(?=\/")/
```

- `(?<=\.)` is a positive lookbehind ensuring that we are starting with a period
- `[a-z0-9]+` will match the actual TLD (.com, .net, .uk, .au, etc)
- `(?=\/")` is a positive lookahead that will match on a forward slash, and just to be safe, a double quote character.

Is this what you are wanting, because here's what a [top level domain actually is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), such as `.com`, `.net`, `.uk`, etc.